# <apex:reportChart> with filter logic

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, analytics

How do I filter  by boolean logic?

You know the way when creating reports, after adding filters, you can add logic to the filters such as OR, AND etc..

How do I change this logic within Visualforce inside the  element? I can define filters, but there's no property to define filter logic. At the moment every time I add a filter it's an 'AND', when really I want an 'OR' for my filters. Can anybody help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to filter it using the following steps:

1. I created a report and added the categories to group it by.
2. I added the filter fields I wanted but left the value blank (E.G. RecordId equals '')
3. I added my Boolean filter logic to the report, and set it up.
4. In my apex controller, I created a new page reference and redirected the user to a custom generated URL using a URL similar to the following:

   `/ReportId?pv0=FilterVal1?pv1=FilterVal2?pv2=FilterVal3`

The report will automatically filter by the filter values provided in the url.

I used this article for reference:

http://www.tgerm.com/2011/04/passing-params-to-reports-salesforce.html

Hope this saves somebody some time + effort.